# Query returns wrong result set - Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm using Entity Framework 4.0.

Custumer is an Entity in my ObjectContext, and the Enity class is autogenerated. I get the customers like this:

```
Public Function GetAll(ByVal companyId As String) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Customer) Implements ICustomerRepository.GetAll
    Return Me.objectSet.Where(Function(p) p.CompId = >companyId).AsEnumerable
End Function
```

My function returns the reult set correct, but it does not select out only the customers where Comp.Id = conmpanyId. I have also tried

```
Return From p In Me.objectSet Where p.CompId = companyId Select p
```

How can I write the query correct?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know the syntax of VB but try this:

```
 Return Me.objectSet.Where(Function(p) p => p.CompId == companyId).AsEnumerable
```